# Stretch ExpandableListView to fill screen vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm an Android newbie. I have an app whose main screen uses an ExpandableListView with only 5 rows. Is it possible to stretch these rows so that they fill the whole screen? Currently only half the screen is occupied and there is a large empty space.

I have tried match_parent, wrap_content for the list's vertical height but nothing helps. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the height attribute on the list does not help because it only tells the listview how much screen space it may occupy.

The individual items your list is displaying are not affected by this, as they will still follow their own layout rules on how to use available space in the listview.

To solve your issue, you might want to look into extending BaseExpandableListAdapter. You can define a custom layout for the listview items, in your case you'd probably just make the item views a bit bigger so they take up more space. You'll find detailed tutorials on how to do this all over the net.

However, using this approach (with a static list size of 5 items), you'll eventually run into the same issue again on devices with larger screens. Your custom list may now look like you want it to on a 4" smartphone, but have a large empty area on a 10" tablet device.

Depending on what purpose you are using the list for, you might want to rethink your UI design approach.